# How to substract TRUE and TRUE in lambda calculus correctly?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I am trying to understand the lambda calculus. However, I am a bit stuck on this expression: TRUE and TRUE. I can't figure out how you can get from

```
((\T F -> T) (\T F -> T))
```

to

```
(\F T F -> T)
```

, not

```
(\F -> (\T F -> T))
```

\ is lambda-signature

[image: graphical explanation]

Comment: Why is the `F#` tag added. I would expect to see some F# code with that tag? I only see `lambda-calculus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\F T F -> T)
```

and

```
(\F -> (\T F -> T))
```

are the same thing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus_definition#Notation:

> - Outermost parentheses are dropped: `M N` instead of `(M N)`
> - [...]
> - The body of an abstraction extends as far right as possible: `λx. M N` means `λx. (M N)` and not `(λx. M) N`
> - A sequence of abstractions is contracted: `λx. λy. λz. N` is abbreviated as `λxyz. N`

In particular,

```
(\F -> (\T F -> T))
```

can be written

```
(\F -> \T F -> T)
```

because we can drop redundant parentheses and the body of the outer lambda extends as far right as possible, which can then be written

```
(\F -> \T -> \F -> T)
```

or

```
(\F T F -> T)
```

by the last rule (contraction).

Comment: Thnx for your answer - it really helps! I think I get what you are sayin'. So, let me get this straight, the reason for removing the redundant brackets is due the fact there aren't any more arguments that can be passed to the function body, right?